# jQuery UI button - how change style and icon checked buttons?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.date').datepicker($.datepicker.regional['cs']);
        $(".votePollState").button({ icons: {primary:'ui-icon-closethick'},text: false });
    });
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="votePollState" id="point-1"/><label for="point-1">Choice 1</label>

<input type="checkbox" class="votePollState" id="point-1"/><label for="point-1">Choice 1</label>
```

I need setting some icons for state of checkbox, no checked checkbox has other icon and checked checkbox has other. No if i check checkbox, this has some icon but only change border color.

Something use ON/OF switch button on iPhone.

THX

Comment: Question is not very clear. Try rephrasing.

Answer (score 12):

You could add a [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) handler that took the [`.checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input) state of the checkbox and assigned the icon based on it, like this:

```
$(".votePollState").button({ 
    icons: {primary:'ui-icon-closethick'},
    text: false 
}).change(function() {
    $(this).button("option", { 
        icons: { primary: this.checked ? 'ui-icon-check' : 'ui-icon-closethick' }
    });
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ryBfh/).

Comment: Your code really works, Thanks! I thinks, jQuery DEV's should add more options for this method to add checked and unchecked icons to button.